# Web8: no endpoint listening error and cms not loading

Tags: web8.5

When i try to connect content porter in SDL Web8.5, I got this issue "There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201603/netTcp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details"

Any one face this issue before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to actually ask a question :) 
I assume you received this error somewhere and are wondering what it means.

Generally speaking, the error occurs when something is trying to talk to the Core Service API and isn't receiving a response. Since it is using a netTcp connection (as per the error message), this is the Core Service that is hosted by the "SDL Web Content Manager Service Host" Windows service.

Most likely the service isn't running or is throwing errors. Try restarting the service and, if the problem persists, have a look at the "Tridion" event log for any error messages from the service.

Comment: Restarted Tridion services not working, final identified issue in web.configuration core services setup issue.